# Custom CCK Currency exposed filter for available currencies

Tags: 7, views, entities

I am trying to set the available currencies programatically like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    /** Modify exposed filter views */
    if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
        $form['field_1hour_currency']['#type'] = 'select';
        $form['field_1hour_currency']['#options'] = array('EUR','USD');
    }
}
```

But I get `An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.` error in the view.

How can I set a select list of available currencies in the views exposed filter for a CCK currency field?

Thank you

(using D6, Views 2 and latest CCK Currency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'myview') {
    // Add our custom All buttons.
    $form['field_1hour_currency']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['field_1hour_currency']['#options'] = array(
      '' => t('<Any>'),
      'USD' => 'USD',
      'EUR' => 'Euro'
    );
  }
}
```

The key is to ensure you include the empty option:

```
'' => t("<Any>")
```

See http://drupal.org/node/463990

You may want to post this solution on your issue on drupal.org too if it works for you: http://drupal.org/node/1155934 ;)

Comment: thank you! I know it's another question, but just in case you already have a link for that. How can I turn that into drop-down select list? (it is now a multiple select box)

Comment: Answered [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/set-dropdown-list-programmatically-in-exposed-view-filters/3665#3665)