# Set dropdown list programmatically in exposed view filters

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have [programmatically set a text CCK to a `select`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/custom-cck-currency-exposed-filter-for-available-currencies) and given a few choices:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'myview') {
    // Add our custom All buttons.
    $form['field_1hour_currency']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['field_1hour_currency']['#options'] = array(
      '' => t('<Any>'),
      'USD' => 'USD',
      'EUR' => 'Euro'
    );
  }
}
```

But this display defaults to a Multiple Choice box, and I want it to be a dropdown list. **How can I set programmatically a `select` to *force single* so it displays a dropdown list?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your form_alter implementation:

```
$form['field_1hour_currency']['#multiple'] = FALSE;
$form['field_1hour_currency']['#size'] = 0;
```